# How to protect LaTeX comment lines from indentation?

Tags: latex, indentation, comment

When I type `<TAB>` in a LaTeX file anywhere on a comment line, the comment symbol is moved to the beginning of the previous non-blank line. This also occurs with `M-x indent-region`.

Is there a way to protect comment lines from indentation and to keep them exactly as I type them? I have tried to set `comment-style` to `plain`, to no avail...

I had the same problem in the past with Fortran 90 files. For some reason, it disappeared in more recent versions of Emacs (I use GNU Emacs 24.3.1), so I hope it should be possible with LaTeX files too.